# apt build-dep fails, unable to locate source package, despite deb-src lines present in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder

Tags: apt, 16.04, compiling, software-sources, emacs

I ran `sudo apt-get build-dep emacs24` and it returned the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for emacs24
```

Now I know the usual advice in this situation, that is, uncomment `deb-src` lines in the `.list` files in your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder (per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158395/apt-get-build-dep-is-unable-to-find-a-source-package). I've tried this though! Every single file in my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder has any deb-src lines in it uncommented. I even ran `sudo apt-get update` after uncommenting these lines! So please help me. Here are the contents of my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder, if you need the contents of any of these files, just say and I'll be happy to provide them.

```
$ ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
alexlarsson-ubuntu-flatpak-xenial.list
alexlarsson-ubuntu-flatpak-xenial.list.save
cpick-ubuntu-hub-xenial.list
cpick-ubuntu-hub-xenial.list.save
damien-moore-ubuntu-codeblocks-stable-xenial.list
damien-moore-ubuntu-codeblocks-stable-xenial.list.save
danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-xenial.list
danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-xenial.list.save
docker.list
docker.list.save
dolik-rce-ubuntu-upp-xenial.list
dolik-rce-ubuntu-upp-xenial.list.save
dotnetdev.list
dotnetdev.list.save
gnome3-team-ubuntu-gnome3-staging-xenial.list
gnome3-team-ubuntu-gnome3-staging-xenial.list.save
gnome3-team-ubuntu-gnome3-xenial.list
gnome3-team-ubuntu-gnome3-xenial.list.save
google-chrome.list
google-chrome.list.save
google-earth.list
google-earth.list.save
icons.list
icons.list.save
jonathonf-ubuntu-golang-xenial.list
jonathonf-ubuntu-golang-xenial.list.save
kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-xenial.list
kubuntu-ppa-ubuntu-backports-xenial.list.save
mmk2410-ubuntu-eclipse-ide-java-xenial.list
mmk2410-ubuntu-eclipse-ide-java-xenial.list.save
mono-jenkins.list
mono-jenkins.list.save
mono-xamarin.list
mono-xamarin.list.save
nodesource.list
nodesource.list.save
noobslab-ubuntu-macbuntu-xenial.list
noobslab-ubuntu-macbuntu-xenial.list.save
notepadqq-team-ubuntu-notepadqq-xenial.list
notepadqq-team-ubuntu-notepadqq-xenial.list.save
runescape.list
runescape.list.save
saiarcot895-ubuntu-myppa-xenial.list
saiarcot895-ubuntu-myppa-xenial.list.save
spotify.list
spotify.list.save
trinity.list
trinity.list.save
ubuntu-elisp-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
ubuntu-elisp-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
unity8-desktop-session-team-ubuntu-unity8-preview-lxc-xenial.list
wine-ubuntu-wine-builds-xenial.list
wine-ubuntu-wine-builds-xenial.list.save
```

If relevant, and you can't tell by the previous bits of information I provided, I am operating on Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to uncomment the `deb-src` lines in the **main** sources file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, not the extra files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

For example, change:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
#deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

to

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
```

Then update the local database:

```
sudo apt update
```

and proceed :)

Comment: Don't forget to `sudo apt update` after. Seems obvious, but I forgot to do this

Comment: thanks @iopq - I updated my answer to include that :)

Answer (score 3):

**`software-properties-gtk` option "Source code"**

From the GUI, you can run:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

then under the "Ubuntu Software" tab click "Source code":

[image]

This has added some `deb-src` lines under `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and now I can do `sudo apt-get build-dep <package>`.

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

**CLI method**

```
sudo sed -Ei 's/^# deb-src /deb-src /' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Tested on the Ubuntu 18.04 Docker image. After this change, I can successful do for example:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep hello
```

and before the change it failed with the error:

```
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

Comment: Not just for the lazy. This (or something similar) is necessary for a script or a Dockerfile.